# Notices when submitting custom post type from front-end

Tags: custom-post-types, errors, input, notices

I have a form in a page template that allows users to submit posts into a custom post type from the front-end:

```
$post = array(
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'post_type' => 'stories',
    'post_content' => wp_kses_post( $story_content ),
    'post_title' => esc_attr( wp_kses( $story_title, array() ) ),
    'post_author' => 4,
);

// Insert story into db
$post_success = wp_insert_post( $post );
```

It works, but I receive these notices

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/username/Sites/the_site/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 776
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/username/Sites/the_site/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 793
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/username/Sites/the_site/wp-includes/general-template.php on line 1645
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/username/Sites/the_site/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 1106
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/username/Sites/the_site/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 1148
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/username/Sites/the_site/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 1106
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/username/Sites/the_site/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 1148
```

I've looked at the files referenced, and it seems to be related to the `comment_status` and `ping_status` of the submitted post, however, I assume that the defaults for `wp_insert_post` should input values for those. Even when I set them in my args array, I get the notices. How to fix this to get rid of the notices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in using the `$post` variable for arguments. After changing this to something like `$new_post` I no longer get the notices.

There must be some conflict with the `global $post` that WordPress uses.

I took this from the Codex, but looking back at the page, I realize that `$post` was just referring the argument name and the actual example in the codex does not use `$post` for the args array.

Answer (score 0):

Insert Data in Custom Post From Front End

```
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == "product") {

    $title     = $_POST['title'];
    $post_type = 'product';
    //the array of arguements to be inserted with wp_insert_post
    $front_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',          
    'post_type'     => $post_type 
    );

    //insert the the post into database by passing $new_post to wp_insert_post
    //store our post ID in a variable $pid
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($front_post);
    //we now use $pid (post id) to help add out post meta data
    update_post_meta($post_id, "short_description", @$_POST["short_description"]);
    update_post_meta($post_id, "price", @$_POST["price"]);
    update_post_meta($post_id, "length", @$_POST["length"]);
```

HTML Code Here

```
<form method="POST">
<label>Product Name</label>
        <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge" name='title'>
        <label>Product Description</label>
        <textarea value="" rows="3" class="input-xlarge" name='short_description'>
        </textarea>
 <label>Price</label>
        <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge" name='price'>
        <label>Dimensions (in):</label>
        <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge" name='length' placeholder="Length">
  <div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Add Product</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="product" />
 </from>
```

Answer (score -1):

Still can't comment it seems, but you have an extra comma in your array.

```
 $post = array(
     'post_status' => 'draft',
     'post_type' => 'stories',
     'post_content' => wp_kses_post( $story_content ),
     'post_title' => esc_attr( wp_kses( $story_title, array() ) ),
     'post_author' => 4, //EXTRA COMMA HERE
 );
```

Maybe that's your problem.

```
 'post_author' => 4,
```

should be

```
 'post_author' => 4
```

Comment: Thanks, however the extra comma isn't the issue. That is valid in a PHP array. I've figured it out, and will post back after I've given others a chance to answer.